# Unity работа с тапом, button

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 вопроса по Button-ам и Тап-ами по коллайдеру:

1. Button работает только когда отпускаешь нажатие? speed прибавляется не при касании, а когда палец убираешь. Есть ли решение?
2. Сам сделал области Тапа, добавив Empty object спрайт кнопки к нему, и добавив Коллайдер чтобы OnMouseDown() работал. Вроде работает, но когда одновременно нажимаю, то вторая кнопка не работает. Как решить проблему с одновременным нажатием на экран?

PS: Одна кнопка прибавляет speed, вторая кнопка прыжка.

Comment: Не нужно выдумывать велосипед - используйте Input.touches с foreach для отслеживания тапов.

Comment: Для обеих кнопок Input.Touches прикрепить? У меня игрок ускоряется каждый раз когда нажимаю Run, и в определенный момент нажимаю Jump и он прыгает, только когда не нажат Run, в этом проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы в свое время когда делали мультитач приложение с возможностью открывать и работать с несколькими окнами одновременно разными пользователями отказались от юнитевского UI в пользу своего обработчика жестов работающего с каждым отдельным окном. Единственным элементом который у нас на всех окнах работает через кнопку это закрытие окна. Поскольку событие с закрытием окон не частое и выполняется быстро, поэтому конфликтами пренебрегли.
Схема такая:

1. Есть в сцене основной менеджер касаний, который запоминает в каком окне касание(по fingerId) зарегистрировано и считает что это касание влияет только на это окно. В самом окне в контроллере регистрируем обрабатываемое касание в отфильтрованный по окну список тачей.
2. В каждом окне есть своя логика по обработке жестов, которая извлекает информацию из списки касаний окна и интерпретирует ее в жесты по количеству касаний, смещению позиций, прошедшему времени и т.п. Логика реакции на жесты определяет что дальше будет с окном.
3. Когда касание прекращается, мы в менеджере касаний определяем за каким окном оно было закреплено и в этом окне из списка касаний его удаляем.

Почему отказались еще от UI в Unity , при тач касании элементов у нас как то странно срабатывали `OnSelect`, `OnDeselect`, `OnPointerEnter`, `OnPointerExit`, `OnPointerDown`. Например при движении окна по экрану после этого касание ранее выделенного окна не давала уже `OnPointerEnter`, а сразу выдавало `OnPointerExit` и `OnDeselect`. Хотя окно сдвинули и отпустили